# How can I find out what is causing namespace error and verify modules from pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm using the package pyJWT extinsively to inspect and manipulate jwts, but suddenly all newly build containers start failing saying `jwt.decode()` do not exists.

I suspect the jwt namespace has been injected from something else, or the cache has been poisoned.

```py
# pip show pyJWT
Name: PyJWT
Version: 2.8.0
Summary: JSON Web Token implementation in Python
Home-page: https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt
Author: Jose Padilla
Author-email: hello@jpadilla.com
License: MIT
Location: /root/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/envs/base/lib/python3.12/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: multitenant-fullstack-test
(base) root@950fc89a6ab0:/test/multitenant-fullstack-test# python
Python 3.12.1 (main, Jan 11 2024, 15:16:36) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import jwt
>>> dir(jwt)
['AbstractJWKBase', 'AbstractSigningAlgorithm', 'JWKSet', 'JWT', '__all__', '__builtins__',
 '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__',
 '__spec__', 'exceptions', 'jwa', 'jwk', 'jwk_from_bytes', 'jwk_from_der', 'jwk_from_dict',
 'jwk_from_pem', 'jwkset', 'jws', 'jwt', 'std_hash_by_alg', 'supported_key_types',
 'supported_signing_algorithms', 'utils']
```

As you see the namespace is quite empty, the workaround for me was to reinstall it:

```py
# pip install pyJWT
Requirement already satisfied: pyJWT in /root/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/envs/base/lib/python3.12/site-packages (2.8.0)

# pip uninstall pyJWT -y
Found existing installation: PyJWT 2.8.0
Uninstalling PyJWT-2.8.0:
  Successfully uninstalled PyJWT-2.8.0

# pip install pyJWT
Collecting pyJWT
  Using cached PyJWT-2.8.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.2 kB)
Using cached PyJWT-2.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Installing collected packages: pyJWT
Successfully installed pyJWT-2.8.0

# python
Python 3.12.1 (main, Jan 11 2024, 15:16:36) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import jwt
>>> dir(jwt)
['DecodeError', 'ExpiredSignatureError', 'ImmatureSignatureError', 'InvalidAlgorithmError',
 'InvalidAudienceError', 'InvalidIssuedAtError', 'InvalidIssuerError', 'InvalidKeyError',
 'InvalidSignatureError', 'InvalidTokenError', 'MissingRequiredClaimError', 'PyJWK',
 'PyJWKClient', 'PyJWKClientConnectionError', 'PyJWKClientError', 'PyJWKError', 'PyJWKSet',
 'PyJWKSetError', 'PyJWS', 'PyJWT', 'PyJWTError', '__all__', '__author__', '__builtins__',
 '__cached__', '__copyright__', '__description__', '__doc__', '__email__', '__file__',
 '__license__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__title__',
 '__uri__', '__url__', '__version__', 'algorithms', 'api_jwk', 'api_jws', 'api_jwt',
 'decode', 'encode', 'exceptions', 'get_algorithm_by_name', 'get_unverified_header',
 'jwk_set_cache', 'jwks_client', 'register_algorithm', 'types', 'unregister_algorithm',
 'utils', 'warnings']
```

Then it is fine again.

I've tried rebuilding the container several times, but this error still appears, so
my current workaround will be to add to the firsts test using jwt to check this and reinstall if required attributes missing.

From perl I'm used to running unittests when installing packages from cpan, is there any way or module that can be used for this?

UPDATE:
`help(jwt)` showed me that `https://pypi.org/project/jwt/` module was installed, but it must have been installed by any of the other mdules, but it does not show up in `pip list`:

```py
pip list
Package                    Version      Editable project location
-------------------------- ------------ --------------------------------
aenum                      3.1.15
aiohttp                    3.9.1
aiosignal                  1.3.1
allure-pytest              2.13.2
allure-python-commons      2.13.2
ansi2html                  1.9.1
attrs                      23.2.0
Authlib                    1.2.0
beautifulsoup4             4.12.3
certifi                    2023.11.17
cffi                       1.16.0
charset-normalizer         3.3.2
click                      8.1.7
colorama                   0.4.6
coverage                   7.4.0
cryptography               41.0.7
curlify                    2.2.1
deepdiff                   6.7.1
dill                       0.3.7
dparse                     0.6.4b0
elastic-transport          8.11.0
elasticsearch              8.11.1
flatten-dict               0.4.2
frozenlist                 1.4.1
h11                        0.14.0
headless-selenium-test     0.1          /test/headless-selenium-test
idna                       3.6
iniconfig                  2.0.0
Jinja2                     3.1.3
jsonschema                 4.21.0
jsonschema-specifications  2023.12.1
jwt                        1.3.1
ldap3                      2.9.1
Levenshtein                0.23.0
markdown-it-py             3.0.0
MarkupSafe                 2.1.3
marshmallow                3.20.2
mdurl                      0.1.2
multidict                  6.0.4
multitenant-fullstack-test 0.1          /test/multitenant-fullstack-test
ordered-set                4.1.0
outcome                    1.3.0.post0
packaging                  23.0
pillow                     10.2.0
pip                        23.3.2
pluggy                     1.3.0
psutil                     5.9.7
py                         1.11.0
pyasn1                     0.5.1
pycparser                  2.21
pydantic                   1.10.13
Pygments                   2.17.2
PyJWT                      2.8.0
PySocks                    1.7.1
pytest                     7.4.4
pytest-cov                 4.1.0
pytest-html                1.0.mortenb-fork-418
pytest-metadata            3.0.0
pytest-reportportal        5.3.1
python-dateutil            2.8.2
python-Levenshtein         0.23.0
pytz                       2023.3.post1
rapidfuzz                  3.6.1
referencing                0.32.1
reportportal-client        5.5.4
requests                   2.31.0
rich                       13.7.0
rpds-py                    0.17.1
ruamel.yaml                0.18.5
ruamel.yaml.clib           0.2.8
safety                     3.0.0
safety-schemas             0.0.1
selenium                   4.16.0
setuptools                 69.0.3
six                        1.16.0
snaptime                   0.2.4
sniffio                    1.3.0
sortedcontainers           2.4.0
soupsieve                  2.5
thefuzz                    0.20.0
trio                       0.24.0
trio-websocket             0.11.1
typer                      0.9.0
typing_extensions          4.9.0
tzlocal                    5.2
urllib3                    2.1.0
wsproto                    1.2.0
yarl                       1.9.4
```

Comment: Have you tried `help(jwt)` inside the Python repl? Apart from the docs it shows you in the last line the file that this specific `jwt` import came from.

Comment: Googling names from the first one got me https://pypi.org/project/jwt/, you probably installed both

Comment: @ivvija - I suspected so but it does not show in `pip list` so what has installed it?

Comment: It is there: `jwt                        1.3.1`. Maybe something like [pipdeptree](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/) will help debug why it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the helpful comments, I found the culprit by grepping the container builds output:

```
#13 63.06 Collecting jwt==1.3.1 (from safety>=2.1.1->multitenant-fullstack-test==0.1)
#13 63.07   Downloading jwt-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
```

So sharing namespace is terribly, I will drop safety
logged a bug towards pyJWT: https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/issues/938

Should be a feature in pip seeing if it installs into a namespace already used.